# What is the maximum number of linearly independent column(/row) vectors in a Matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm studying for an exam and are practicing old exam questions. A frequent question that I don't understand is the following:

*What is the maximum number of linearly independent column vectors in Matrix A where:*

$$A=\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
-2 & 2 & 4 & 2 \\
-3 & 1 & 6 & 3
\end{matrix}$$

How do I go about solving these types of questions? I would also like to be able to answer  the same question but for rows.
The material we have does not appear to cover this and while I have reached out to my teacher I have not gotten a reply yet.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of linearly independent columns of a matrix is equal to its maximum number of linearly independent rows. It is called the *rank* of the matrix. It is also equal to the maximum size of a square submatrix with non-zero determinant.

Comment: I did not succeed in finding a duplicate. If someone does, I am ready to delete my answer.

Comment: Ok, then my follow-up question is "How do I go about figuring out the maximum number of linearly independent rows/columns? How do I know if a column/row is independent? 

P.S. I realize I am several months late in my reply. I apologize for this.

Comment: These are *two* "follow-up questions". I already gave one of the possible answers to the first one (using determinants), but an answer to the second question (once corrected) can also play this role (and conversely, determinants can help to prove independence). The second "follow-up question" makes no sense as it is. You probably mean "how do I know if *a set of* vectors is independent?" Just apply [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence).